# XPath to return value only elements containing the text

Tags: xpath

would like to return value of 'Earnings per share' (i.e. -7.3009, -7.1454, -19.6295, -1.6316)
from "http://www.aastocks.com/en/stocks/analysis/company-fundamental/earnings-summary?symbol=01801"

using below as a example for '-7.3009'
`=importxml("http://www.aastocks.com/en/stocks/analysis/company-fundamental/earnings-summary?symbol=01801", "//tr/td[contains(text(),'Earnings')]/td[2]")`

However, it returns #N/A.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

this xpath will return your specific data

```
id("cnhk-list")//tr[td[contains(., "Earnings Per Share")]]/td[starts-with(@class, "cfvalue")]//text()
```

xpath explanation in english is " you actually needs to select  the td where row contains `Earnings Per Share` which is in table that has some specific ID